# Is it possible to use the layout in the _app.jsx component with next-i18next?

Tags: react-hooks, next.js, next-i18next

To create a site, I use nextjs, when creating pages, I took the general layout with the header and footer into a separate hoc component and wrapped the page components in the file with it `_app.jsx`:

```
function App({ Component, ...rest }) {

  const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...props.pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Everything worked fine until localization became a problem, after using the `next-18next` library for translations and adding `serverSideTranslations`, two errors began to appear on each page:

```
 react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next
frontend-node_1      | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'label')
frontend-node_1      |     at DropdownSwitcher (webpack-internal:///./src/components/header/translation/DropdownSwitcher.jsx:45:36)
frontend-node_1      |     at renderWithHooks (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
frontend-node_1      |     at renderIndeterminateComponent (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)
frontend-node_1      |     at renderElement (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
frontend-node_1      |     at renderMemo (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5868:3)
frontend-node_1      |     at renderElement (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6011:11)
frontend-node_1      |     at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
frontend-node_1      |     at renderNodeDestructive (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
frontend-node_1      |     at renderNode (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
frontend-node_1      |     at renderHostElement (/app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5642:3)
```

The error with "label" occurs because the i18n object is empty on the server:

```
const DropdownSwitcher = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation()

  const currentLanguage = useMemo(() => {             // language as undefined 
    return LANGUAGES.find((item) => item.language === i18n.language)
  }, [i18n.language])
  ....
```

But everything is fine on the client and there are no errors. What could be the reason and how to fix it, since the App itself from the `_app.jsx` file is wrapped in `appWithTranslation` from `next-i18next`.

Therefore, two questions arise, how to fix `react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next` and why there is no i18n object on the server?

I moved the layout to the level of the page itself, removing it from _app.js, but for some reason, then something, `useEffect()` is repeated in the header, although the header component has not changed in any way and bringing the layout to the level of `_app.jsx` fixes it

If there is not enough information or you need a visual example, I will try to create a small program that demonstrates this with open source. Please write in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, but I forgot to provide an answer here, but I noticed that someone also has this problem, so I will try to help people who come across this post, although it is relevant only for `nextjs` version 12, since with the appearance of version 14, the structure there has improved a lot with as I think there should be no more questions like mine.

**1. Rendering the layout**

In the official doc, there is a whole section that describes how to correctly [divide the layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts) so that it works according to the SPA type.

*pages/index.jsx*

```
// pages/index.jsx

import Layout from '../components/layout'
import NestedLayout from '../components/nested-layout'

export default function Page() {
  return (
    /** Your content */
  )
}

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <NestedLayout>{page}</NestedLayout>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

pages/_app.js

```
// pages/_app.js

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

This component method approach is much better than using its direction in `_app.jsx` because you can extend or replace them and not make a crude monolith, example how I used it:

```
// pages/ingex.jsx

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <HomeLayout>
      <Main />
    </HomeLayout>
  )
}

HomePage.getLayout = (page) => <MainLayout>{page}</MainLayout>
```

```
// pages/about-us.jsx

const AboutUsPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HomeLayout>
        <AboutUs />
      </HomeLayout>
    </>
  )
}

AboutUsPage.getLayout = (page) => (
  <MainLayout withNav>
    <LayoutContext.Consumer>
      {({ device }) => device.isMobile && <NavigationMobile />}
    </LayoutContext.Consumer>
    {page}
  </MainLayout>
)
```

With this approach, react still works like a spa and a similar page to `about-us`, which will also have `NavigationMobile`, will simply compare it.

**2. Error with next-i18next**

The whole point was that the next-i18next library was configured incorrectly in the first place (more precisely, it needed to be corrected). In order to configure everything correctly, I had to do the following:

*- Move the folder with translation files to the public folder.* This is necessary so that the library config, which we will configure a little below, can see the translation files and interact with them

*- Configure next-i18next.config.js to work with the client.* Here is an example setup with some comments. And also a link to the [documentation](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next#6-advanced-configuration), and some other resources I found while setting up.

next-i18next.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

const LANGUAGES = ['en', 'pl', 'uk']
const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'

// if it is the server, then the full path, if the client, then the relative path.
const localePath =
  typeof window === 'undefined' ? path.resolve('public', 'translation') : '/public/translation'

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
    locales: LANGUAGES,
    fallbackLng: LANGUAGES,
    nsSeparator: '::',
    keySeparator: '::',
    // How to use libraries for i18next like LanguageDetector
    use: [require('i18next-intervalplural-postprocessor')],
    serializeConfig: false,
  },
  localePath: localePath,
}
```

*- Configure next-i18next in the _app.jsx file.* Here everything is as described in the documentation.

```
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import nextI18NextConfig from '../../next-i18next.config'


function App({ Component, ...rest }) {
  const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest)
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)

 //WARNING!!! You don't have to have your own i18next initialization like i18next.use(LanguageDetector).use(intervalPlural).init({ detection: options }) this is all done by the next-i18next library

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppHOC>{getLayout(<Component {...props.pageProps} />)}</AppHOC>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default appWithTranslation(App, nextI18NextConfig)
```

*- You need to pass the config when calling the serverSideTranslations function.* To make your life easier, it is better to transfer the implementation of this function to another file, here is an example of how I did it:

```
// utils/serverSideTranslations.js

import { serverSideTranslations as baseServerSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations'
import { dt } from '../../constants/defaultTranslate'
import { DEFAULT_LANGUAGE } from '../../constants/languages'
import nextI18NextConfig from '../../../next-i18next.config.js'

const serverSideTranslations = async (locale, domains = []) => {
  return await baseServerSideTranslations(locale, [...dt, ...domains], nextI18NextConfig, [
    DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
  ])
}

export default serverSideTranslations
```

*- And finally, use this function on the pages.*

```
import MainLayout from '../components/layouts/MainLayout'
import serverSideTranslations from '../utils/serverSideTranslations'
import HomeLayout from '../components/home/HomeLayout'
import Main from '../components/home/main/Main'

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <HomeLayout>
      <Main />
    </HomeLayout>
  )
}

HomePage.getLayout = (page) => <MainLayout>{page}</MainLayout>

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  // Wrapping in Promis.all is not necessary, I use it simply so that if there are any other asynchronous operations, then not to use them through await and not to block each other's work
  const [translations] = await Promise.all([
    serverSideTranslations(locale, ['home']),
  ])

  return {
    props: {
      ...translations,
    },
  }
}

export default HomePage
```

I hope this helped someone, if you have any comments, write in the comments

Comment: Thanks! Setting up localePath solved it for me